# "Bad state: Future already completed" in Aqueduct

Tags: dart, aqueduct

I'm attempting to, in the `prepare` method of the main channel, load up an `AutoRefreshingAuthClient` and subsequently a `FirestoreAPI` object, but I am getting the following stack trace:

```
Unhandled exception:
Bad state: Future already completed
#0      _Completer.completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:21:31)
#1      ApplicationIsolateSupervisor._handleIsolateException (package:aqueduct/src/application/isolate_supervisor.dart:129:24)
#2      ApplicationIsolateSupervisor.listener (package:aqueduct/src/application/isolate_supervisor.dart:102:7)
#3      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1314:10)
#4      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
#5      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:263:7)
#6      _SyncStreamController._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:764:19)
#7      _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:640:7)#8      _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:586:5)
#9      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
```

Though this stack trace does not point to anything in my code, I isolated the issue to an awaited `clientViaServiceAccount` call (code below) in the `prepare` method.

I'm unsure as to what I'm doing wrong as the documentation for this API ([googleapis](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/googleapis)) is largely unhelpful in this context, and the example method shown in the documentation doesn't seem to work here.

**How do I properly set up the `AutoRefreshingAuthClient` and `FirestoreAPI` objects without getting this exception?**

This is an Aqueduct project that has no issues running if I simply run the example code shipped with the project at creation.

I've tried shifting the calls and initialization to different scopes, but aside from that I don't know what to try.

### channel.dart

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:googleapis/firestore/v1.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';

import 'package:mm_block/mm_block.dart';
import 'package:mm_block/controller/member.dart';

final _credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(
  File('credentials').readAsString()
);
final _scopes = [
  FirestoreApi.CloudPlatformScope
];

class MMBlockChannel extends ApplicationChannel {
  FirestoreApi firestore;

  @override
  Future prepare() async {
    // The issue is here.
    await clientViaServiceAccount(_credentials, _scopes)
      .then((client) => firestore = FirestoreApi(client));
  }

  ...
}
```

This should all run correctly and I should end up with an `AutoRefreshingAuthClient` being passed to the `FirestoreAPI` call.

Comment: What happens when you move this line of code to a simple Dart script? If you are using await, you don't need to use .then. Just assign the return of await clientViaServiceAccount(...) to a variable and then pass that variable to FirestoreApi's constructor.